# Why does URL change in browser when traffic forwarded from Reverse Proxy (port 8080) to Wordpress site listening on port 80

Tags: wordpress

I'm testing a 3rd party vendor Reverse Proxy to be able to forward traffic to various web servers on the backend. In this particular case, the RP is listening on port 8080 and based on the URL it detects (abc.example.com:8080/abc), it'll pass on the traffic to the a backend server for e.g: 192.168.0.60 listening on port 80. Now when I type the the address in the web browser as follows: abc.example.com:8080/abc, the response comes back with connection time out and the URL has changed to abc.example.com/abc in the browser. It basically strips off the port from within the URL. The browser then tries to connect to abc.example.com/abc but can't get anywhere since there is no path directly to the backend server.

Following is the .htaccess configuration on the backend server running WAMP

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /abc/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /abc/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://abc.example.com:8080' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://abc.example.com:8080' );
```

On startup, Wordpress checks whether the given URL matches the defined URL for the site and if it does not match then Wordpress performs a redirect. So, I think your Wordpress is performing the redirect because it is does not consider ":8080" to be part of its defined site URL.